# How do you say "chubby" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

There was once - in the Third Century A.D., to be precise - an attractive, intelligent, giggly girl from an affluent Roman family whose nickname was "Chubby." She did not mind - it made her laugh.

Dictionaries suggest "Pinguis," but wouldn't there be a feminine form as well?

Comment: It's an adjective from the 3rd declension. The male and female are the same.

Comment: @ManuelCauãRebouças: Even as a nickname?

Comment: @Ricky Sure. But *pinguis* just means “fat” anyway. You want a diminutive, and those generally happen to have unabiguous female forms. Figulus gives two examples for diminutives based on *pinguis*.

Answer (score 9):

There are doubtless many ways to say this. The first that come to my mind are *Pinguicula* or *Pinguiuscula*, either of which could work as a nick name. Both are classically attested adjectives, though neither are used as nick names so far as I know.

Comment: Very nice. Not classically attested, but used here and there in Neo-Latin (plus a number of scientific species names): *obesula*.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel: Doesn't "obesula" mean obese rather than just chubby?

Comment: @Ricky it's also a diminutive, in this case of *obesa* (well nourished, stout, fat).

Comment: @Ricky Obesity is a modern concept that doesn't translate over well to the ancient Romans. Both words mean "fat," and the Romans never developed a BMI index to distinguish between a bit chubbiness and obesity. For other words, you also have *opima*, but there's no classically attested diminutives, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel *Obesula* is a great find. It would make a great answer.

Comment: @cmw *Opima* is a great suggestion. It hardly needs a dimimutive. It already comes with such pleasant associations. It too would make a great answer.

Comment: @cmw the Romans may not have calculated BMIs, but see Mart. Ep. 11, 100 

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Excellent find, and it gives me an idea for an answer!

Comment: @cmw, I await your answer on tenterhooks!